# symfony making server cpu 100 % usage

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine-orm, doctrine

I have symfony ver. 5 project which runs perfectly fine in local but in production a simple doctrine insert in database make CPU usage 100% which results in memory usages full and 500 server error.

```
$em = $this->getDoctrine()->getManager();
$role->setStatus(true);
$em->persist($role);
$em->flush();
```

```
server memory => 4 GB,
os => aws amazon linux 2 ami,
php => 8,
doctrine => 2.8
```

this simple code which update status only causing 100% CPU usage and memory usages to full and halt the script.

I have tried disabling logger in symfony, clearing variables, increasing server memory with no luck.

Comment: can you provide any log?

Comment: what kind of DBMS are u using?

Comment: @Abilogos i am using aws aurora mysql rds . error is something like this => Allowed memory size of 134217728 bytes exhausted (tried to allocate 116224000 bytes) at /var/www/html

Comment: seems that your PHP process is restricted to only 128 mib in your PHP ini settings

Comment: What have you tried to resolve the problem? Where are you stuck? Usually, the given code should not cause such problems.